# TypeError: Odd-length string

Tags: python, string, int, hex

I have the following code

```
for i in range(0, len(c1)):
    m = (pow(int(c1[i]), (p - 1 - d), p) * int(c2[i]) % p) % p  
    print m
    m2.append(binascii.unhexlify('%x' % m))
```

The values of m are as follow 
104
1701604463
544045344
1851878757
543781664
1634625377
1948267808
1751477356
1864396153
544104813
1696622963
543256167
1634994792
1701604463
544045344
1851878757
543781664
1634625377
1946839141
1819045664
1836654702
1634559264
1769152609
1852268916
174613868

Then I get

```
line 73, in decrypt
    m2.append(binascii.unhexlify('%x' % m))
TypeError: Odd-length string
```

Its breaking at 174613868? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: "This function [binascii.unhexlify] (...) must contain an even number of hexadecimal digits (which can be upper or lower case), otherwise a TypeError is raised."
(https://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.unhexlify). I don't know your code, but check if you can pad left with 0 (if odd-length string).

Comment: Thanks padded left with 0 if odd and did unhexlify using string